# MySQL takes 10 seconds for counting with conditions on for 100k records

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, products.id AS products_id 
FROM `products` 
INNER JOIN `product_device_facilities` 
  ON `product_device_facilities`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `product_vendors` 
  ON `product_vendors`.`ProductId` = `products`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `screen_shots` 
  ON `screen_shots`.`ProductVendorId` = `product_vendors`.`id` 
WHERE ( (DownloadCount >= 10 or DownloadCount is NULL) 
  and (Minsdk <= 10 or Minsdk is null)) 
GROUP BY products.id 
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(device_facility_id ORDER BY device_facility_id ASC ) IN (0)
```

This is taking 10 seconds for 100k records.

How to improve the performance?

Comment: What is the table engine? InnoDB? Post your query "explain" statement.

Comment: (And remember that not all us gora know what a lakh is.)

Comment: Engine is InnoDB. How to get the explian statement?

Comment: This is infact a rails generated Query for product find Product.page(page.to_i).per(10).joins(:product_device_facilities, :product_vendors => [:screen_shots]).includes(:product_device_facilities, :product_vendors => [:screen_shots]).where(conditions).group('products.id').having(having).order(order)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things that you can try.

1. Use persistent connections to the database to avoid connection overhead
2. Check that all of your tables have Primary keys on the key tables e.g. (product_id)
3. Use less RAM per row by declaring columns only as large as they need to be to hold the values stored in them. i.e. as @manurajhada said don't use count(*) use count(primary key)
4. Using simpler permissions when you issue GRANT statements enables MySQL to reduce permission-checking overhead.
5. use indices on the references between different tables. just remember not to index too many columns, simple rule of thumb, if you never refer to a column in comparisons, there’s no need to index it.
6. Try using [ANALYZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html) to help mysql to better optimize the query.
7. You can speed up a query a tiny bit by making sure all coumns which are not null are declared NOT NULL — thus you speed up table traversing a bit.
8. Tune MySQL caching: allocate enough memory for the buffer (e.g. SET GLOBAL [query_cache_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_size) = 1000000) and define [query_cache_min_res_unit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_min_res_unit) depending on average query result set size.
9. I know it sounds counter intuitive but sometimes it is worth de-normalising tables i.e. duplicate some data in several tables to avoid JOINs which are expensive. You can support data integrity with foreign keys or triggers.

and if all else fails

1. upgrade your hardware if you can, more RAM, faster HDD can make a significant difference to the speed of the database, and when you have done that allocate more memory to mysql.

**EDIT**

- Another option if you do not require the results live as @ask-bjorn-hansen suggested you could use a background task (cron job) once a day, and store the result of the query in a separate table, then in your application all you have to do is check that table for the returned result, that way you get around having to query 100k results and would be able to run queries that take hours and not overly impact your users.

Comment: Using count(*) will use the primary key column, so using count(some_other_column) will at best give the same results in the same speed, but might even give different results depending on the data.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply.I have tried 1-7, but no luck:(. Now the only thing left is tuning the cache. I need them on the fly as the input params keep on changing.But testing with the group concat removed, reduced it by 2 seconds.Seems i am in deep trouble.

I am doing device filtering actually for an android phone. The value in my in might change.

Answer (score 1):

Do indexing on join columns on tables and instead of count(*) use count(some indexed primary key column).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no luck! I have already indexed the join table foreign keys. Still this is taking time.Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Are minsdk and download count in the same table?  If so adding an index on those two might help.

It could be that it's just a hard/impossible query to do quickly.  Without seeing your full schema and the data it's hard to be specific, but it's possible that splitting it up into several easier to execute queries would be faster.  Or as Amadeus suggested maybe denormalize the data a bit.

Another variation would be to just live with it taking 10 seconds, but make sure it's always done periodically in the background (with cron or similar) and never while a user is waiting.  Then take the time to fix it if/when it takes minutes instead of seconds or otherwise puts an unacceptable burden on your user experience or servers.

Comment: MinSdk and downloadcount are already indexed. But the Cardinality seems to be small for minsdk and large for download count. Is that to do anything with performance?

Comment: Yeah, that's likely.  Are they indexed in the same index?  If so then make sure that downloadcount is first.  (Of course if the cardinality is high but 90% of the rows are > 10 then it won't help).   What does MySQL say if you add `explain ` in front of the query?  (Probably finish it with `\G` instead of `;`).

Comment: 1 | SIMPLE | products| index | PRIMARY,Minsdk,product_index_download | PRIMARY| 4| NULL
1 | SIMPLE      | product_vendors| ref   | PRIMARY,productvendorindex            | productvendorindex | 5       | appmall_dev.products.id|1 | Using where; Using index |

Comment: |  1 | SIMPLE      | screen_shots              | ref   | productvendorindex                    | productvendorindex | 5       | appmall_dev.product_vendors.id        |      1 | Using where; Using index |

|  1 | SIMPLE      | product_device_facilities | ref   | product_id                            | product_id         | 5       | appmall_dev.product_vendors.ProductId |      1 | Using where


This is the explain

Comment: How many rows do you have in the products table?  Does it also take a long time if you leave out the join and just fetch from the products table?  (It looks like your where clause parameters are all from there).

Comment: I have 1,23,400 records in the products table. No, its taking just few seconds if i left the joins out, but the same is not possible. Because i am using a RubyonRails query to fetch products, screen shots and some fields from the product_vendors join table as well, ALL IN ONE SINGLE QUERY. This sql query is generated by the pagination library "kaminari" for finding the number of pages in the products table.